# Issue checking value of form input with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I want to perform an if statement based upon the value of a hidden input within myform.

the scenario is that I have a table consisting of tests. Each test is essentially its own form. the hidden input basically contains 'YES' if the test has a password attached. I want to prompt the user to enter the password if that is the case when they attempt to execute a particular test (submit the form).

so here is my code I am attempting:

```
$("#submit").live('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).parent().find(':input:hidden[name=has_password]').val() == 'YES') {
            $('.messagepop').remove();
                $(this).parent().append('<div class="messagepop pop"><p><label for="password">Enter test password</label><input type="text" size="30" name="pass" id="pass" /></p><p><input type="button" id="submitPass" value="GO" id="pass_submit"/> or <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p></div>');
                $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
                $("#pass").focus();
                });
                return false;
    }  
});
```

Without the if statement the code works: on clicking a particular button within a form, another small password entry form pops up. However I only want the form to pop up if a value of a hidden input is 'YES'.

I have checked that values are present in the hidden input.

I imagine I am using the jQuery slightly wrong as I am a beginner. So can somebody identify a better way of performing the check?

Many thanks,

**EDIT (jsfiddle with html etc):**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezFgU/12/)

Comment: Your code seems fine. We need more context to find the actual problem. It would be best if you can recreate the scenario in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Hi brian, As far as I can see it, this is essentially what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/ezFgU/11/ and it works on jsfiddle :P

Comment: @brianpeiris  how is his code fine the selector is incorrect

Comment: @buymypies what you show as html in your post is not valid html and doesn't match what is in your fiddle  can we see the html source

Comment: @mcgrailm The selector is [perfectly valid for jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/hDNgN/) but I agree with you about the invalid HTML, it could be the cause of the problem. @buymypies In the future, consider running your HTML through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: @mcgrailm, sorry, follow the link to the fiddle to see source html.

Comment: @mcgrailm, updated fiddle, i was playing around with changing the hidden status of input and link was to the wrong one. apologies.

Comment: @brianpeiris  ok then jquery is forgiving in the api  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ they always have quotes around the name

Comment: @buymypies your js fiddle still has invalid html get that sorted out first. the form needs to be in a td the items in the form should not be without a parent in the form every submit button needs a different id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is extremely malformed. The `<tr>` and `<form>` end-tags are mismatched, you've got a `<form>` tag directly inside the `<tr>`, which is not allowed, you haven't self-closed your `<input />` tags and you have duplicate id's on the same page.

```
<tr>
  <form name='myform' method='post' action='test_sim.php'>
    <input name='test' type='hidden' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='has_password' value='NO'>
    <td>TEST 1</td>
    <td>B352</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>2011-05-12 06:00:00</td>
    <td>2011-05-12 12:00:00</td>
    <td>06:00:00</td>
    <td><input id='submit' type='button' value='execute test'></td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

It should be like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>TEST 1</td>
  <td>B352</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>2011-05-12 06:00:00</td>
  <td>2011-05-12 12:00:00</td>
  <td>06:00:00</td>
  <td>
    <form name='myform' method='post' action='test_sim.php'>
      <input name='test' type='hidden' value='1' />
      <input type='hidden' name='has_password' value='NO' />
      <input class='submit' type='button' value='execute test' />
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Fixing the HTML solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/ezFgU/16/

You should use the [W3C Validator tool](http://validator.w3.org) to check your HTML so that you can prevent these types of issues.

Edit: As mcgrailm mentioned, your `id` attributes are duplicated. jQuery is forgiving here, it seems, that's why the above jsFiddle works. You should use a class to identify your submit buttons and use the corresponding `$('.submit')` selector to attach a click handler.

Comment: thank you! it seems I've learnt a lot from such a small task.

Comment: please note that you should not leave inputs in the from without a parent to have valid html  so you should put them in divs or ul->li

Comment: @mcgrailm Only if you're aiming for Strict validation, I think. [The HTML5 spec allows it](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/forms.html#the-form-element).

Answer (score 1):

i believe

```
if ($(this).parent().find(':input:hidden[name=has_password]').val() == 'YES')
```

should be

```
 if ($(this).parent().find('input[name=has_password]:hidden').val() == 'YES')
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your selector is incorrect try this

```
$("#submit").live('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).parent().find('input[name="has_password"]:hidden').val() == 'YES') {
            $('.messagepop').remove();
                $(this).parent().append('<div class="messagepop pop"><p><label for="password">Enter test password</label><input type="text" size="30" name="pass" id="pass" /></p><p><input type="button" id="submitPass" value="GO" id="pass_submit"/> or <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p></div>');
                $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
                $("#pass").focus();
                });
                return false;
    }  
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/ezFgU/)

Comment: ye, I have tried it. I just get nothing happening on the clicking #submit now.

Comment: I don't understand why its not working :( Must be something to do with having multiple forms...but they are all seperate so I am lost

Comment: can you post the html also if you are using an actual submit button you will need to prevent the default I updated my fiddle to show how to do that

Comment: Can you give your forms different identifiers?

Comment: @PMV i've removed form id's that was jst there coz i was trying a different approach.